# Why aren't monad transformers constrained to yield monads?

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass, monad-transformers

In the [MonadTrans](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#MonadTrans) class:

```
class MonadTrans t where
    -- | Lift a computation from the argument monad to the constructed monad.
    lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a
```

why isn't `t m` constrained to be a Monad?  i.e., why not:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
class Monad (t m) => MonadTrans t m where
  lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a
```

If the answer is "because that's just the way it is", that's fine -- it's just confusing for a n008.

Comment: If `t` is a monad, its kind must be `* -> *`, whereas kind of `t m a` is `* -> * -> *`, I think (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: Does it make sense to apply monad operations to "values" of `t m` ? Are there values of `t m` at all?

Comment: Oops, didn't mean to leave out that constraint.  Added it.  Thanks.

Comment: @EarlGray, no there are none.  `t m` has kind `* -> *`, and types (i.e. the types of values) have kind `*`.  But it similarly does not make sense to apply monad operations to "values" of `Maybe`, because there are none.

Comment: @MattFenwick The `Monad m` constraint needs to go into the class head in your suggestion, you cannot constrain class parameters in the member functions.

Comment: One reason why the class is defined as is and not in your way is, at least for the `transformers` package, portability. MPTCs are a language extension, so using them isn't portable.

Comment: @Daniel re: constraint location -- ghci accepts the code as is without warnings, at least on my machine.

Comment: @MattFenwick Aha, change in how the extension behaves between ghc-6.12 and 7.0 (when GHC got its new type checker). Didn't know that. 6.12.3 requires `FlexibleContexts` additionally.

Comment: In their paper "Monad Transformers and Modular Interpreters", Liang, Hudak and Jones actually suggest doing something like this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You suggested the following:

```
class Monad (t m) => MonadTrans t m where
    lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a
```

...but does that really mean what you want? It seems you want to express something like "a type `t` may be an instance of `MonadTrans` if, for all `m :: * -> *` where `m` is an instance of `Monad`, `t m` is also an instance of `Monad`".

What the class definition above *actually* says is more like "types `t` and `m` may constitute an instance of `MonadTrans` if, for those specific types, `t m` is an instance of `Monad`". Consider carefully the difference, and the implied potential for instances that may not be what you'd want.

In the general case, every parameter of a type class is an independent "argument", a fact which has been a bountiful source of both headaches and GHC extensions as people have attempted to use MPTCs.

Which isn't to say that such a definition couldn't be used anyway--as you point out, the current definition is not ideal either. The age-old problem "Why `Data.Set` Is Not a `Functor`" is related, and such issues helped motivate the recent `ConstraintKinds` tomfoolery.

The ultimate answer to "why not" here is almost certainly the one given by Daniel Fischer in the comments--because `MonadTrans` is pretty core functionality, it would be undesirable to make it depend on some terrifying cascade of increasingly arcane GHC extensions.