# Why isn't lift's return value constrained to be a monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass, monad-transformers

Why isn't `MonadTrans` defined as

```
class MonadTrans t where
    lift :: (Monad m, Monad (t m)) => m a -> t m a
--                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead of current

> ```
> class MonadTrans t where
>     lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a
> ```

This is Haskell 98 (unlike the suggestion in [Why aren't monad transformers constrained to yield monads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13686714/1333025)) and ensures that the result will always be a monad. Is there a reason why monad transformers are allowed to produce something that isn't a monad?

Comment: Why do you want to ensure the result is a monad?  That would be strictly less general, and I don't see any benefit from it.

Comment: @JohnL Primarily because [`MonadTrans` laws](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#t:MonadTrans) are expressed in monadic terms so the result must be a monad. If it isn't, the laws can't even be expressed. But bheklilr made a good point in his answer and based on that I made an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18495255/1333025) that produces a `Monad` -> `Applicative` transformer. However, this means we need to formulate a different set of laws.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that a `MonadTrans` transforms a `Monad` into something else, instead of transforming a `Monad` into a `Monad`.  It's more generalized, since you might write something that transforms a `Monad` and you can define `lift`, but you can't define `>>=` and `return`.  Since most (if not all) `MonadTrans` instances end up being `Monad`s, it doesn't really present a problem as the compiler still handles it just fine.

Comment: No personal knowledge, but I expect this is the reason.  It seems plausible that you might want a `MonadTrans` instance for a `Functor` or `Applicative` that isn't a `Monad`.

Comment: @JohnL This was exactly my reasoning.  I'm not citing any sources, because I don't know any sources (so if anyone has that documentation feel free to post it), but it would make sense that a MonadTrans only operates on a single monad, rather than two.

Answer (score 6):

bheklilr's answer gave me idea of an example where a monad transformer produces something that isn't a monad. A well-known example of something that isn't a monad is `ZipList`. And we can make a variant that runs a monadic action at each level:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Arrow ((***))
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans

-- | A list where each step is produced by a monadic action.
data ListT m a = Nil | Cons (m (a, ListT m a))
```

This is actually a monad stream. And it can be easily made into a `Functor` and an `Applicative`

```
instance Monad m => Functor (ListT m) where
    fmap f Nil      = Nil
    fmap f (Cons k) = Cons $ (f *** fmap f) `liftM` k
instance Monad m => Applicative (ListT m) where
    pure x = Cons $ return (x, pure x)
    Cons mf <*> Cons mx = Cons $ do
        (f, fs) <- mf
        (x, xs) <- mx
        return (f x, fs <*> xs)
    _       <*> _       = Nil
```

but obviously not a monad. So we have a `MonadTrans` instance that converts a monad into something that's only an `Applicative`.

```
instance MonadTrans ListT where
    lift mx = Cons $ (\x -> (x, lift mx)) `liftM` mx
```

(This whole thing made me realize that an experimental [`ZipSink`](https://github.com/ppetr/conduit/blob/251c6f5d47dd5161a88172e67e4342dcb3df77d2/conduit-extra/Data/Conduit/Extra/ZipSink.hs) in *conduit-extra* is also a nice such example.)

---

However, this raises another question: If we want such transformers, what laws should they adhere to? The laws for `MonadTrans` are defined as

> ```
> lift . return = return
> lift (m >>= f) = lift m >>= (lift . f)
> ```

So in our case we could wish for something like

```
lift (f `liftM` x)  = fmap f (lift x)

lift . return       = pure
lift (m `ap` f)     = lift m <*> lift f
```

Comment: Note that if you wrap your `ListT` in one last monad layer then it is a monad, specifically ["ListT done right"](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ListT_done_right).

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Yes, remembering `ListT` was my inspiration. But my `ListT` defines `pure` and `<*>` differently, just as [`ZipList`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) is different from `[]`. So it doesn't have a valid monad instance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to disagree with the other two answers to say that the result should be a monad.  The reason why is that otherwise there are no sensible laws that `lift` should obey.

`lift` is supposed to be a monad morphisms, meaning that it should obey the following two laws:

```
lift (return x) = return x

lift (m >>= f) = lift m >>= \r -> lift (f r)
```

These laws make more sense when you realize they are functor laws between two Kleisli categories:

```
-- i.e. "fmap id = id"
(lift .) return = return

-- i.e. "fmap (f . g) = fmap f . fmap g"
(lift .) (f >=> g) = (lift .) f >=> (lift .) g
```

However, if you don't constrain the output to be a monad then those laws are no longer valid and you have no sensible way to verify that you implemented `lift` correctly.

I suspect the real reason was to make the class Haskell98

Comment: My idea of `lift :: (Monad m, Monad (t m)) => m a -> t m a` seems to be H98. So you'd suggest that for things like `ZipListT` we should rather use another, applicative transformer with something like `lift :: (Applicative f) => f a -> t f a`?

Comment: @PetrPudlák I don't know the real reason for the lack of the constraint, so I'm just guessing.  What laws would the applicative transformer obey?

Comment: I'd imagine an applicative transformer should obey the applicative laws, and a functor transformer need obey only the functor laws.  Although most likely it would be a pointed functor, so `lift . pure = pure` should still be valid.  I think that would be quite enough to work with.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I suggested some laws (just guesses) at the end of my own answer.

Comment: @PetrPudlák I like those laws.  Just note that the the first law is automatically true because of parametricity, but the other two are nice.